# Isolated bridge in Debian

Tags: networking, debian, bridge

According to [Is it possible to enable port isolation on Linux bridges?](https://serverfault.com/questions/388544/is-it-possible-to-enable-port-isolation-on-linux-bridges), it is possible to create isolated ports in `isolated on` with the `bridge` command. This uses the `BR_ISOLATED` flag for the interface. Isolated ports have been implemented in other tools, such as `virsh` for [1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1727263).

How can we configure an isolated bridge in Debian using `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Edit: ifupdown is used to parse the `interfaces` file, which points to `man bridge-utils-interfaces` [for reference](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/-/blob/master/examples/bridge?ref_type=heads). It seems that is not possible to use the isolated option directly on the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Just `apt install ebtables` and add those commands into the `up` (or `post-up`, its alias) into the corresponding interface definition:

```
iface br0 inet static
    bridge-ports eth0 ...
    ...
    up ebtables -P FORWARD DROP
    up ebtables -F FORWARD
    up ebtables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT # let the traffic flow from uplink to any ports
    up ebtables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT # let the traffic flow from any ports to uplink
```

It might be worth splitting the per-interface parts out to these interface's definitions.

If there is many rules, you can collect them into a script and call that script from the `post-up` action instead. Or, you can also use `netfilter-persistent` or other firewall manager that supports saving and restoring the `ebtables` rules, and manage the firewall out of `interfaces` file. There will be no errors even if the interface still doesn't exists during the ruleset loading (or command invocation), the rule will not be removed when the interface gets deleted for whatever reason, and it will work once there appears an interface with the declared name. So it's safe. I'd actually prefer this way of managing it.

It's worth noting that Proxmox VE has a Web GUI that manages this for its VMs and containers.

Comment: This is not the `ebtables` option but rather the `bridge link`. While it is possible to add a hook once the interface is created, you should be able to pass this configuration directly.

Comment: Well, this is what you can do *now*. If you think this is not enough (although I don't get why using `post-up` hooks doesn't suit you), you can implement this functionality into the `ifupdown` (or better, `ifupdown2`) package and send them a pull request, if you think that one "should be able to pass this configuration directly". Or you can also implement your own hooks instead of using standard "post-up"/"pre-down" in the form of executable scripts into `if-down.d  if-post-down.d  if-pre-up.d  if-up.d`. In any case, this will boil down to shell scripting, there is no ready made solution.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to use `bridge link`? I can accept it as a temporary workaround